# $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare()) not working

Tags: wordpress

I am creating simple displaying lists of uses in wordpress. I am using below code for that

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE name = %s",$name);
```

This above query is not working because of  " $wpdb->users " that is table name but when I use only "users" that is table name it works.

Please help me whether am I missing something in the code

Comment: Why not use this function? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: Or get_user_by https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by

Comment: There is no field `name` in the wordpress users table. According to the latest wordpress version, you have: `user_login`, `user_nicename`, `display_name`. Are you using any other custom table?

Comment: You did not close the second parenthesis of the get_results function.

Answer (score 1):

use `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("..."))` instead.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class